# ConEmu: Open a new shell of the same configuration with a GuiMacro

Tags: conemu

How can I open up a new ConEmu shell of the same configuration?

For example, currently I open a new git bash shell with this GuiMacro:

`Shell("new_console", "{Bash::Git bash}", "", "%CD%")`

How can I make this more generic? So that if I am in a git bash shell, it will use `{Bash::Git bash}`; but if I am in a cmd prompt, it will use `{Shells::cmd}`

Comment: Look at `Ctrl+Shift+O` shortcut.

Comment: @Maximus That's close to what I want, but I'd like the duplicated process to open in a new tab

Comment: So what? The macro is an example , just remove splitting.

Comment: Duplicate: https://superuser.com/q/1195935/139371